# how to pass the ID of the link that was clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ejs

I'm having a problem trying to pass a unique ID when a link is clicked. I'm making an API call and looping through the JSON data and rendering it on the client side. The problem is when the link is clicked all the ID's in the JSON object get passed when I only want the ID of the object that was clicked.

Here is my loop:

```
<% apiResultsdata['items'].forEach(function(items) { %>
    <% let ID = items['id'] %>
    <% let volumeInfo = items['volumeInfo'] %>
    <% let author = volumeInfo['authors'] %>
    <% let title = volumeInfo['title'] %>
    <% let image = null %>
    <% if(!(volumeInfo['imageLinks'] === undefined)) { %>
      <% image = volumeInfo['imageLinks']['smallThumbnail'] %>
<% } %>
```

This is the link with the title that should be clicked:

```
<a class="clicklink" href="/bookDetails"><%= title %></a>
```

This is the ajax code I'm using to pass the ID:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                      $(document).ready(function(){
                          $(".clicklink").click(function() {
                            $.ajax({
                              type: 'post',
                              contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
                              data: JSON.stringify({ID:'<%= ID %>'}),
                              url: 'http://localhost:3000/bookDetails',
                              success: function(data){
                                console.log('success');
                              }
                            });
                          });
                      });
                  </script>
```

Again all the IDs associated with items get passed, when I only want the id of the book that was clicked. Thanks.

Comment: First you get pass the book id on anchor element as attribute `book-id`

``<a class="clicklink" href="/bookDetails" book-id="<%= ID %>" ><%= title %></a>``


later you can retrieve it using jquery in pass in it ajax.

`var bookId = $(this).attr("book-id");`

`data: JSON.stringify({ID:bookId}),`

Comment: Also try to stop propogating the anchor element after you sent a ajax request. just do `return false` at end of click function

Comment: @Rafee that didn't work either. It still passes all the ID's

Comment: can you inspect element and what you see for book-id attribute?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/FAtH9P0t